# Перевести код с языка Java на Pascal

Tags: java, pascal

```
var a, b, c, d, e;

for (a = 1; a <= 50; a++) {
for (b = 1; b <= 50; b++) {
for (c = 1; c <= 50; c++) {
for (d = 1; d <= 50; d++) {
for (e = 1; e <= 100; e++) {
if ( (a + c + d == 50)&& (e - 30 + b == 50) ) {
console.log('a = ' + a);
console.log('b = ' + b);
console.log('c = ' + c);
console.log('d = ' + d);
console.log('e = ' + e);
console.log('summ = ' + (50 + 50 + 30 + a + b + c + d + e));
console.log('---------');
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: А в чем у вас конкретно проблема? Вы не знаете как на паскале цикл писать?

Comment: С паскалем вообще не дружу, по этому решил обратится с помощью с людям которые знают больше меня)

Comment: не очень понятно где и что у вас не получается, на каком месте проблемы начинаются

Comment: К примеру если брать начало этого кода:
for (a = 1; a <= 50; a++)
В Паскале цикл for обычно имеет начало, и конец, тут 3 параметр. Как это понимается?

Comment: Тот же самый инкремент в java, в паскале не имею понятия как реализовать.

Comment: Наверное нужно почитать книжку по паскалю или найти в интернете как пишутся циклы на паскале?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например цикл в паскале:

```
for a := 1 to 50 do
 begin
  ваши остальные циклы
 end;
```

дальше чтобы вывести код в консоль нужно сделать так:

```
writeln('some message', some variable)
```

по поводу условий - пишется условие так:

```
if a + c + d = 50  then 
 if e - 30 + b = 50 then 
  writeln('some message', some variable)
 break; // выходим из цикла
```

возможно есть в коде синтаксические ошибки, не спорю. На паскале ничего не делал уже давненько :(
вот есть [туториалы](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_nested_if_statement.htm). И вот онлайн [сервис](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_pascal_online.php), где можно пробовать и тестировать. Там все красиво и понятно реализовано, и если у вас будут ошибки то вам об этом скажут.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!